# What is "external dns hosting"?

Tags: dns, hosting, external

Some internet service providers seem to provide "external dns hosting". How does it work? And what would you use it for?

I don't really know what else I should write about my question.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather, it is about DNS hosting.  In the future use [webmasters.se] for questions about your website, [sf] for questions about your servers, and [networkengineering.se] for questions about professionally managed computer networks.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What they mean is that they allow you to use a DNS server for your domain that is not one of their own.

Generally a service provider will have some kind of web form and/or API to enter information into DNS for your domain. This information will then be served by DNS servers under control of the service provider.

If they offer "external DNS hosting", they will point your domain to another DNS server (that you specify) instead.

One reason for wanting this could be that you want to use a more advanced DNS service then the provider itself offers. Route53 comes to mind.

You might also be concerned about the same party controlling both your service and the domain allowing it to be accessed. Imagine the provider would cease to exist: you could restore your service with any other provider but would be unable to make your domain point to it.

Comment: Maybe splitting your answer into paragraphs would make it clearer?

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your swift reply and this great answer to my question. Much appreciated.